# implementation left slide menu app in ios

Tags: objective-c

I want to have a left slide menu in my ios app like facebook app.
But I don't get how I can implement this.

The way I thought was

I have

LeftMenuController : UITableViewController 
which has left menu view

and
MenuNavigationController : UIViewController
which contains LeftMenuController instance as a class variable

Finally I make my custom view controllers extending MenuNavigationController class
so that each view controller can use left slide menu.

But the problem is when I click row in my left menu I want to pushviewcontroller Controller A but A controller should also be MenuNavigationController type.

So MenuNavigation Controller imports LeftMenuController, and LeftMenuController imports A controller which is extended from MenuNavigationController. Because it's referencing each other as a loop so app crashes here...

I think this kind of method is quite silly but is there any way to solve this problem?
Or could you please suggest a better way of implementing this kind of app?

Comment: Please take the effort to google it first, then if your stuck at some point post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This open source project seems to fit your needs perfectly https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu :)

Answer (score 0):

One vote for [JASidePanel](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) . Very simple to use and clean. I have used in my app for sometime and it works great.